# short int Integer wrap around / short int inversion in c not understood, difference between assignment and prints

Tags: c, types, integer, integer-overflow

The following code fragment

```
short int k = -32768;
printf("%d \n", -k);
k=-k;
printf("%d \n", k);
```

prints

```
32768 
-32768
```

I would assume that both prints are equal.
Can somebody explain what the difference is and why the assignment `k=-k` causes a wrap around? It was hard to find a explanation online, as i don't really know what to google.

Comment: Integer Promotion strikes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to *print* a `short`, you need to use a length modifier.

Change the format string to `%hd`.

Comment: So the exact answer is: %d treats the variable as an integer, hence no wrap around occurs. the assignment treats it as short, which results in a wrap around. with %hd, the print also treats k as a short, and we get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Because `SHRT_MIN = -32768` and `SHRT_MAX = +32767`. Check out how 2's complement work.

#### Edit

Actually, according to the international standard of the C programming language (i.e. [*Committee Draft — May 6, 2005*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), pp. 50-51) regarding signed integers:

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit.
>
> There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one sign bit.
>
> Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <= N).
>
> If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value.
>
> If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>N</sup> ) (two's complement);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>N</sup> − 1) (ones' complement).
>
> Which of these applies is **implementation-defined**, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones' complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and magnitude and ones' complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a negative zero.

So, in other words, in your case it's seems that 2's complement is being used, but this should not be assumed to be in all platforms and compilers.

Comment: Why is it different in the print and in the assignment, should the wrap around not also occur when i just print -k, instead of assigning it, as above

Comment: @FalcoWinkler I guess in the print the number is being interpreted as a int (not short).

Comment: @FalcoWinkler `k=-k;` does nothing, since `32768` cannot be represented by `short`. It is out of range.

Comment: @WeatherVane of course it does something, it assigns 32768 to k, which wraps around to -32768. Your comment says, every time you assign something that cannot be represented, the assignment is not executed? Thats wrong

Comment: Then why are you asking a question you know the answer to? I meant that `k` is unchanged, therefore it does nothing. There is never a point at which k == 32768 and then "wraps".

Comment: i asked why it is different in the print and assignment

Comment: You asked "why the assignment k=-k does not invert the value?"

Answer (score 1):

`-32768` is `8000` in hexadecimal notation. `32768` can not be represented as a signed 16 bit number, therefore the compiler promotes `-k` to an `int` with the hex value `00008000`. When this number is assigned to the 16-bit variable, the high bits are truncated, resulting in `8000` or `-32768` again.